# Google Adwords Conversion Tracking code form submission

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have to put a Google Adwords Conversion Tracking code on a page which is a simple form. This form have no destination but only call a php page that just send a mail.

it's look like this extract :

```
<?php
    if($valid) {
        header('location:process.php');
    }
?>
<form action="inc/form.php" method="post" id="contact-cab">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

how can i be sur to track the submission of this form without having "thanks page" ?
Thanxs

Answer (score 0):

A form requires a thank you page. You're asking the script to track the conversion in the background of the code of your page - which it can't do. Not impossible though - just hard.

Best thing would be to create a lightbox modal for example and show a message Thank You. It's far easier to create a modal that executes your code rather than figure out how to get the conversion script to track it for you.